# Use Settings Sync or Syncing vscode extensions with remote SSH environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using **VSCode 1.38.1** and I connect to a remote docker environment running sshd with SSH using the **Remote - SSH 0.46.1** extension.

Everything works smoothly and I can install/uninstall extensions in the remote docker container with the VSCode.

However, I cannot find a way to use the **Settings Sync 3.4.3** (latest) extension to sync my extensions/settings in the remote docker container.

It seems that it can be installed only locally and not on the Remote SSH environment. Is there any way to use it with the remote environment?

Also, could you please suggest me an alternative settings syncing extension? I have also tried **Syncing 3.0.9** extension which can be installed remotely but when I download the extensions/settings from the gist file it loops forever.

[image].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating a symbolic link from .vscode-server to .vscode in the remote environment everything works smoothly. Also, only the Syncing extensions 3.0.1 version works correctly with syncing.

Comment: Can you elaborate for us non-native Ubuntu users?

Answer (score 0):

I try the same way, it looks still not working.
I am connecting the remote linux server(not container), the remote server specific setting is not synced to gist after "Upload/Update Settings",  it looks only local PC setting uploaded to gist.

did you try to configure remote specific setting (which is not same as local PC) and sync it?